Is @PostUpdate supposed to be called when you're modifying data in a one-to-many collection?
I'm using Hibernate for my JPA.  I marked a method as @PostUpdate but it does not appear to be called if I save the object but only make the changes to an entity in a sub collection
@EntityListeners({FooListener.class})
@Entity
public class Foo {
  @Id long id;
  @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @Getter
  List<Bar> bars;
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
  @Id long id;
  @ManyToOne(optional=false)
  // also tried cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER
  Foo foo;
  @Getter
  @Setter
  String data;
}

@Component
public class FooListener {
  @PostPersist
  public void afterPersist() { log.debug("PostPersist"); }
  @PostUpdate
  public void afterUpdate() { log.debug("PostUpdate"); }
}

public interface Foos extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {}

What I was expecting is the PostUpdate message to appear when I do
@DataJpaTest
@WebAppConfiguration
class DemoApplicationTests {
  @Autowired Foos fooRepository;
  @Autowired TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

  @Test
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
  void contextLoads() {
    final var idRef = new AtomicLong();
    transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult(
        tx -> {
          var f = new Foo();
          var b = new Bar();
          b.foo = f;
          b.data = "b";
          f.bars.add(b);
          idRef.set(fooRepository.save(f).id);
          System.out.println("got " + idRef);
        });

    transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult(
        tx -> {
          var foo = fooRepository.findById(idRef.get()).orElseThrow();
          foo.bars.get(0).data = "Z";
          fooRepository.save(foo);
        });
  }
}

But in my case I didn't see it.
Related to When updating an ElementCollection does it trigger the @PostUpdate of the containing object? but this one does not deal with ElementCollectionand rather plainEntity` objects

Nothing has changed in the Foo-table.

That's correct but I set the thing to CascadeType.ALL

It appears to require a spec change at least it's tagged as a candidate for the next release after the last nudge.
To work around this I had to create another field on Foo and remember to update it to a different value like an incrementing number to trigger an update.  Note @Version doesn't do it either but it does act like the optimistic locking version.
